# Problem with empty rows with pandas and python

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to create a dictonary with some data from two columns.
The information I need is in different rows, so I tried filling the empty rows on the first column, and then I tried to append both columns, but it didnt work. The first column is filled with 'NaN' when I try to append.

Does anyone has other aproach to solve this?
Thanks in advance

My intention is to get a result like this:

`{'Group A' : ['Z', 'A', 'S', 'X', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'V', 'F], 'Group B': ['A', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'E', 'V', 'Q', 'S'], 'Group C':['Q', 'E', 'R', 'T', 'F', 'D', 'S', 'A', 'Z']}`

Here is what Ive tried so far

```
#I fill the rows with information and it works.
Gp = df[['Groups']].ffill(axis = 0)
Lt = df[['Letters']]

#But as soon as I try to append both rows, the Gp rows become NaN 
Append = Gp.append(Lt)
```

Here is an example of my excel file:

```
Groups  Letters


Group A         


            Z
            A
            S
            X
            C
            D
            E
            V
            F
Group B         


            A
            C
            D
            F
            G
            E
            V
            Q
            S
Group C         


            Q
            E
            R
            T
            F
            D
            S
            A
            Z
```

[image]

Comment: What is your dataframe like after you read from the excel file?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a step by step solution:

Read the data from the Excel file to a `pd.DataFrame` (The xlsx file 'text.xlsx' is same as the excel screenshot with all the empty rows and columns as you have in the question)

```
df = pd.read_excel(open('text.xlsx','rb'))
```

Since there are empty rows and empty columns (as per your sample), remove them. The empty cells will have `NaN`s. The first `.dropna()` will drop the rows and the second `.dropna()` with `axis=` will drop the columns. The option `how='all'` will remove the rows/columns only if all the values are `NaN`s.

```
df = df.dropna(how='all').dropna(how='all', axis=1)
```

Now you will have 2 columns - one for 'Groups' and one for 'Letters'. The 'Groups' column will have `NaN`s for all except the first row of each group. The corresponding 'Letters' column value for the first group will be `NaN`. Fill the `NaN`s in the 'Groups' column with the previous row value using `method='ffill'`. And then drop the row with `NaN`s in the 'Letters' column (as it is not needed)

```
df['Groups'] = df['Groups'].fillna(method='ffill')    
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Finally, you have only the 'Groups' and 'Letters' without `NaN`s. Group the `DataFrame` by 'Groups' column and convert them to `list` and them to a `dict` - as shown below.

```
print(df.groupby('Groups')['Letters'].apply(list).to_dict())
```

Result:

```
{'Group A': ['Z', 'A', 'S', 'X', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'V', 'F'], 'Group B': ['A', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'E', 'V', 'Q', 'S'], 'Group C': ['Q', 'E', 'R', 'T', 'F', 'D', 'S', 'A', 'Z']}
```